# How to add sub node_modules to .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-bash

Basically I've created a new repository for small features that my team uses in several projects.

The structure is the following:

```
[feature1]

|-- [node_modules]

[feature2]

|-- [node_modules]
```

1) How can I add all the node_modules inside each feature (same repository for all of them) ?

I've tried :

```
*/node_modules/
*node_modules/
```

2) Is there a way to create a branch for each feature and still all the team members can access them? Or do you think a full repository with all the features and if someone decides to improve one just merge it to the master after they are done?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at Git submodules

Answer (score 3):

1) Just `node_modules/` works for me. But if node_modules is already tracked by git. You need to remove it first by doing `git rm -r --cached feature1/node_modules/`

Comment: but if I do `git status` the node_modules appear as untracked

Comment: That's weird. Sure you have added the .gitignore file correctly? Also you can check if the files within node_modules is tracked by git using this command: git ls-files | grep node_modules

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly it's been a few years since this question has been asked and git has been updated more than a few times, but the (relatively) new Azure Functions local development tools install node_modules for each Function folder.  This means that anyone using this will be going through the same thing if they use git/vsts.

```
Function A
  |_node_modules
Function B
  |_node_modules
```

This was the exact syntax in .gitignore that worked for me in VS Code to remove all node_modules placed under any subdirectory:

```
*/node_modules
```